# PhoneRTC in Ionic 2

Tags: ionic2, phonertc

I'm planning to create a WebRTC based Ionic 2 application so was wondering if PhoneRTC is fully supported in Ionic 2.

Also, what are the alternatives available if it's not.

Comment: did you used this in your app? help me please with some sample tutorials/code

Comment: @varunaaruru : No, I didn't use PhoneRTC, it seems to be an old library which is not updated any more. I'd suggest you to look at iosRTC https://github.com/eface2face/cordova-plugin-iosrtc which seems to be updated regularly.

Comment: are you still trying to build it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first phone rtc https://github.com/alongubkin/phonertc  is a cordova plugin but it is nit supported under the hood of ionic native.

But you can still use third party plugins functionality through the plugins namespace on Window:

> window.plugins.somePlugin.doSomething();

See [**this too**](https://www.joshmorony.com/using-cordova-plugins-in-ionic-2-with-ionic-native/)(see it under the title `Using a Plugin Not Included in Ionic Native`)